# Emgu CV Image sharpening and controur detection

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, emgucv

I am working on a project where I need to identify dots from IR lasers on a surface. I use for that a camera with IR filter
Some input images:

[image]

[image]

There can be several dots, too. So I tried to sharpen this image from webcam and then use FindContours method of Emgu CV.
There is my code:

```
public static Image<Gray, byte> Sharpen(Image<Gray, byte> image, int w, int h, double sigma1, double sigma2, int k)
{
    w = (w % 2 == 0) ? w - 1 : w;
    h = (h % 2 == 0) ? h - 1 : h;
    //apply gaussian smoothing using w, h and sigma 
    var gaussianSmooth = image.SmoothGaussian(w, h, sigma1, sigma2);
    //obtain the mask by subtracting the gaussian smoothed image from the original one 
    var mask = image - gaussianSmooth;
    //add a weighted value k to the obtained mask 
    mask *= k;
    //sum with the original image 
    image += mask;
    return image;
}

private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs arg)
{
    Mat frame = new Mat();
    if (_capture.Retrieve(frame, CameraDevice))
    {
        Image<Bgr, byte> original = frame.ToImage<Bgr, byte>();
        Image<Gray, byte> img = Sharpen(frame.ToImage<Gray, byte>(), 100, 100, 100, 100, 30);
        Image<Gray, byte> thresh = new Image<Gray, byte>(img.Size);
        CvInvoke.PyrDown(img, thresh);
        CvInvoke.PyrUp(thresh, thresh);
        Image<Gray, byte> mask = new Image<Gray, byte>(thresh.Size);
        Image<Gray, byte> cannyImg = thresh.Canny(10, 50);

        VectorOfVectorOfPoint contours = new VectorOfVectorOfPoint();
        Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
        CvInvoke.FindContours(
            cannyImg,
            contours,
            hierarchy,
            RetrType.External,
            ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple
            );

        Image<Bgr, byte> resultImage = img.Copy().Convert<Bgr, byte>();

        int contCount = contours.Size;
        for (int i = 0; i < contCount; i++)
        {
            using (VectorOfPoint contour = contours[i])
            {
                resultImage.Draw(CvInvoke.BoundingRectangle(contour), new Bgr(255, 0, 0), 5);
            }
        }

        captureBox.Image = original.Bitmap;
        cvBox.Image = resultImage.Bitmap;
    }
}
```

Example of result image:

[image]

So it almost all the time works as I expect it to, but framerate is very low. I'm getting like 10-15 fps with resolution of 640x480. I need to be able to do the same thing for 1920x1080 with at least 30 fps. It's my first time with OpenCV and Emgu.CV. What can I do to make it perform better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this just setting the threshold, so that image turns black and white only. By adjusting the threshold I was able to achieve the same results if not better in terms of clarity, but also performance drastically improved since there is not heavy processing going on

Here is a snippet with ARCore library instead on EmguCV

```
var bitmap = eventArgs.Frame;

            var filter = new Grayscale(0.2125, 0.7154, 0.0721);
            var grayImage = filter.Apply(bitmap);
            var thresholdFilter = new Threshold(CurrentThreshold);
            thresholdFilter.ApplyInPlace(grayImage);

            var blobCounter = new BlobCounter();
            blobCounter.ProcessImage(grayImage);
            var rectangles = blobCounter.GetObjectsRectangles();
```